# How do you distinguish when a question should be asked at SE movies vs. SE scifi?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

There are a lot of questions on http://scifi.stackexchange.com which relate to Sci Fi movies and TV shows.

It seems like this site would be the place to ask those questions.

Is there a difference between asking it here vs. asking it at scifi?

Comment: I have alerted the Sci-fi mods about this question to see if they can give a more clearer explanation of what may constitute as better asked here.  Personally, the view for me is as long as it is a viable question in accordance to our [FAQ] I'm perfectly ok with it.

Comment: and good question, and good proactive actions @TylerShads

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It would be nearly impossible to keep the scope of all SE sites mutually exclusive, and SciFi and Literature are clearly sites which overlap with us. This issue is seen across SE.

Partially it comes down to personal preference. You might feel more comfortable in one site or another.  SciFi is a more established site, has a great community of followers so undoubtedly there are going to be questions there that would also be suitable here, but that is the site they are happiest posting in.

You might also prefer a perspective of a movie goer or sci-fi addict, so would choose one site or another. For instance you are probably going to get more responses from SciFi if the question is about underlying SciFi themes or ideas, or links to the book that a movie is adapted from (though this is also often covered here). Here the perspective is going to be more about the movie, even if there is prior media such as books or comics.

It is generally discouraged to migrate questions between sites purely to try to get them into the (subjective) best site. If it is on-topic for the site it is generally left there.  The SciFi mods are aware of us, and do migrate questions that clearly would be better handled here, such as a lack of SciFi content to the question.

Comment: +1 good answer, thank you!

Comment: but why don't you guys create a link to these questions so as if there is an identical questions on site **A**  & **B** there will be a cross link to these sites so as readers can actually get more intel from different perspective, meaning rich content tackling both science and entertainment, that will be awesome does it make sir mod?

Comment: @Elltz - I don't think we're going to systematically look for and create links to questions on other sites - while SciFi has the clearest overlap, we do overlap with other sites too.  Its a collaboratively edited site, so users are always welcome (and do) include links to related questions on other sites in comments.