# Should anime questions be migrated to anime.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

How should we approach to this situation?

What goes to movies.stackexchange and what goes to anime.stackexchange related to animes?

**Details:**

**movies.stackexchange** has `anime` tag but there is no `identify-this-anime` tag. There is `identify-this-tv-show` tag which can be applied to animes, I suppose.

**anime.stackexchange** has `identification-request` tag

---

Is this related to this question also:
[SciFi/Movies overlap](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/scifi-movies-overlap/12#12)

And I think this is a related question also regarding to sci-fi:
[How do you distinguish when a question should be asked at SE movies vs. SE scifi?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376/how-do-you-distinguish-when-a-question-should-be-asked-at-se-movies-vs-se-scifi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed this is very related to the whole Movies-SciFi-Overlap discussion and to be resolved in more or less the same way. Thus there is naturally overlap between *Movies & TV* and *Anime & Manga* but this does neither mean anything anime is to be migrated from this site to *Anime & Manga* nor that a question would be closed as a duplicate if a similar question from another user already exists over there. One is the subject matter and the other is the medium. This makes questions about animes perfectly on-topic on both sites and it is just a matter of preference where you ask them.

Neither is there any need for an `identify-this-anime` tag, as animes are as well movies or TV-shows as any other animated movies or series (we don't have tags for `identify-this-columbus-movie` or `identify-this-sitcom` either). What you can do is use additional tags, like the mentioned `anime`-tag, in addition to `identify-this-movie/tv-show`, which are (along with many other genre-tags) there to further specify ID-questions.

Comment: Could not have put it better.